# Sub that returns a value

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way that I can call a block of code and get the value that I am looking for and store it as the variable I want and then use it in a different sub?

For example. I want to search all the values in row 1 starting at A1 and going till the there is a blank value. I want to find the cell with the value "Frequency" in it and then return the column index number.

```vb
Sub findFrequency()
    'find "Frequency" colum and save the column index number
    Dim fFreq As String
    Dim FreqCol As Variant
    Range("A1").Select
    fFreq = "Frequency"
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell.Value = fFreq Then
             FreqCol = ActiveCell.Column
             Exit Do
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now ideally I can write a different sub and use the value from the above code.

```vb
Sub Execute()
    Call findFrequency
    Cells(5, FreqCol).Select
    With Selection.Interior     
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

I get an error when I run this because the value of FreqCol is not set to anything from running the Call findFrequency line.

Comment: `Sub` can't return a value (but it can assign value to a global variable). What are you looking for is `Function`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Function findFrequency()
    'find "Frequency" colum and save the column index number
    Dim fFreq As String
    Dim FreqCol As Variant
    Range("A1").Select
    fFreq = "Frequency"
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell.Value = fFreq Then
            findFrequency = ActiveCell.Column
            Exit Do
        End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
End Function

Sub Execute()
Dim FreqCol As Long
FreqCol = findFrequency()
Cells(5, FreqCol).Select
With Selection.Interior     
     .Pattern = xlSolid
     .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
     .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
     .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
     .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why loop or select a cell to find a value? Simply use `.Find`

```
Function findFrequency() As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:="Frequency", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then findFrequency = aCell.Column
    End With
End Function
```

Also what should happen if the "Frequency" is not found. You need to cater to that as well.

```
Sub Execute()
    Dim FreqCol As Long

    FreqCol = findFrequency

    If FreqCol = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "Frequency not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Cells(5, FreqCol).Interior
         .Pattern = xlSolid
         .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
         .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
         .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
         .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me to the answer by 2 hours @Siddharth.  I'm thinking of writing the `Find` answer as a template so I can copy/paste it in and answer in less than a second. :)

Comment: Well I have sort of it ready [Here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) :D

Comment: Yes, have had a look at your site.  I keep meaning to set one up myself, but I haven't anything new to add to the mix yet.

Comment: But then I also have [Handy Code Viewer](http://www.siddharthrout.com/downloads/) Most of my code snippets are stored there.

Comment: I've nothing as fancy as that - just a folder full of `.bas` files with names like `mdl_EXCEL_RANGE_FindLastCell.bas` which I just drag and drop into my projects.

Answer (score 0):

The code would to be like this.

Main Main sub is findFrequency,  subprocedure is Sub Execute(rng As Range)

```
Sub findFrequency()
        'find "Frequency" colum and save the column index number
        Dim fFreq As String
        Dim FreqCol As Variant
        Range("A1").Select
        fFreq = "Frequency"
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
            If ActiveCell.Value = fFreq Then
                FreqCol = ActiveCell.Column
                Execute Cells(5, FreqCol)
                Exit Do
            End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Loop
End Sub
Sub Execute(rng As Range)

With rng.Interior
     .Pattern = xlSolid
     .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
     .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
     .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
     .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

let me tell you that you should not apologize for asking a basic question about VBA: nobody deserves to spend time with VBA and I'm glad you are more acquainted with other programming languages.

I write my answer for all people not familiar with VBA.

VBA passes arguments by default by reference so you can write your code in this way:

```
Sub findFrequency(FreqCol as Long)
...
End SUb 

Sub Execute()
    Dim FreqCol As Long
    findFrequency FreqCol 
    ... 
End SUb
```